# On a functional of one-dimensional Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes

I have a question about a positive functional of the one-dimensional Brownian motion.

Let $(\{B_t\}_{t \ge 0},P_x)$ be the one-dimensional Brownian motion starting from $x >0$.

I would like to know whether the following equation holds
\begin{align*}
\text{(A)}\quad \lim_{x \to \infty}P_{x}\left(\int_{0}^{\sigma_1}\frac{1}{B(s)}\,ds \ge a\right)=1\quad \text{for any $a>0$.}
\end{align*}
Here, $\sigma_1=\inf\{t>0 \mid B_t=1\}$.

Namely, I would like to whether $\int_{0}^{\sigma_1}\frac{1}{B(s)}\,ds$ is very large.

**Attempt**

It holds that
\begin{align*}
&P_{x}\left(\int_{0}^{\sigma_1}\frac{1}{B(s)}\,ds \ge a\right) =P_{x}\left(\exp \left(-\int_{0}^{\sigma_1}\frac{1}{B(s)}\,ds \right) \le \exp(-a)\right).
\end{align*}

Hence, to prove (A), it suffices to show
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to \infty} E_{x}\left(\exp \left(-\int_{0}^{\sigma_1}\frac{1}{B(s)}\,ds \right) \right)=0.
\end{align*}

Let $f(x)=2x\log x-2x$. Then, $f'(x)=2\log x$ and $f''(x)=2/x$.
Therefore, we have
\begin{align*}
f(B_t)=f(x)+2\int_{0}^{t}f'(B_s)\,dB_s+\int_{0}^{t}(1/B_s)\,ds
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
&\exp\left(-\int_{0}^{\sigma_1}\frac{1}{B(s)}\,ds \right) \\
&=\exp(-f(B_t))+\exp(f(x))+\exp(2\int_{0}^{t}f'(B_s)\,dB_s)...
\end{align*}
However, I feel that this argument is not good.

Please let me know if you know a good proof method.

Comment: If you want to have it quick, then you can take a look at the Handbook of Brownian motion, Table 1, formula 2.19, which gives an explicit expression for the Laplace transform which you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I would like to look at the book.

Comment: @saz I could find the formula. It seems that $\lim_{x \to \infty}P_x(\int_{0}^{\sigma_1}1/B_s^2\,ds \ge a)=0$ holds too.